# Simple program compiled without error gives a white page

Tags: elm

I compiled the "[Hello world](http://elm-lang.org/examples/hello-html)" program

```
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "Hello, World!"
```

with elm 0.17 on Windows, without compile errors:

```
elm make hello.elm --output index.html
```

When I open Chrome on index.html, I get a blank page.  Chrome's console shows 2 errors in index.html :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _elm_lang$virtual_dom$VirtualDom$text is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm is not defined
```

If I run the elm-reactor on that file, I also get a white page, and similar errors in the console.

Somehow, a path is missing...  Here is the elm-package.json file:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
"repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
"license": "BSD3",
"source-directories": [
    "."
],
"exposed-modules": [],
"dependencies": {
    "elm-lang/core": "4.0.0 <= v < 5.0.0",
    "elm-lang/html": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
},
"elm-version": "0.17.0 <= v < 0.18.0"
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: I used elm.  I edited my question.

Comment: FWIW, this happened to me on a mac and your solution worked there as well. I don't think this was a Windows specific issue as your title suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting the elm-stuff subdirectory.  At the next make, it reinstalls the missing packages, and everything works fine.

Comment: This saved me, thanks. I was going crazy. It worked on one computer, not on another...