# Uncaught ReferenceError: _elm_lang$virtual_dom$VirtualDom$text is not defined

Tags: elm

I have a pretty small elm application that I have been working on. Things have been going okay, but now I getting a runtime error that I can't figure out.

My elm app compiles just fine with `elm make` or even with `elm reactor` but when I load the page I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _elm_lang$virtual_dom$VirtualDom$text is not defined`

My elm-package.json seems fine:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "",
    "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [
        ".",
        "./src"
    ],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "4.0.1 <= v < 5.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.17.0 <= v < 0.18.0"
}
```

My first thought is that something is wrong with my package deps, but I can't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your elm-stuff directory and recompiling. It sounds like this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551769/simple-program-compiled-without-error-gives-a-white-page-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry I didn't try that sooner, would have saved me a lot of time!